# Linking workbookA sheet1 cell A1 to workbookB sheet1 cell A1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to link data from one workbook to another workbook

I have master workbook which need to be open as "RUN AS ADMINISTRATIVE" and from that master workbook I have given several link to another work sheets in different workbooks.

the issue is, if I do open master workbook as normal than, automatic link updates immediately, but when I run master workbook as an administrative then links not updating automatically.

when I open master workbook as an administrative, formula look likes this

`='E:\ARSHIT IPO\MY SHEETS\O.C. ANALYSIS\OPTIONS\new\NEW\[MASTER SHEET.xlsm]MASTER'!A2`

when I open master sheet as normal in such case formula look likes this

```
='[MASTER SHEET.xlsm]MASTER'!A2
```

what I have tried so far :-

I have tried enabling automatic data update option and my external data options can be checked from 
below image.

I don't know where I am lacking, kindly help with this issue.Any help ll be appriciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While in the same workbook (Excel file), you shouldn't need to specify the name of the file.

Have you tried it like this?

```
=MASTER!A2
```

Comment: Sorry, in that case I didn't get your question.

Do you definitely want it to update automatically? Else you could probably try this with macros

Comment: yes, I am sure with my requirement, I want it to update automatically.